# \bibitem like commands in moderncv

Tags: bibliographies, moderncv

I an learning `moderncv` class to create my own cv. Formerly I was using `res` class to create the same. I want to know how to insert bibliography manually (without using a `.bib` file ) in `moderncv` using commands similar to

```
\begin{thebibliography}{20}
\bibitem{} ... \\
...
\end{thebibliography}.
```

Comment: you should be able to do that (although why not use bibtex) if you got an error show an example so someone can debug.

Comment: `thebibliography` takes an argument, as in the standard classes which is missing in your fragment

Comment: Please see a similar question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593078/161015. Using `filecontents` you create a bib file without pain and `bibtex` will guide you to the errors if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example can you use the following bibliography containing two books:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{adams}
Douglas Adams.
\newblock {\em The Restaurant at the End of the Universe}.
\newblock The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. Pan Macmillan, 1980.

\bibitem{Goossens}
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
\newblock {\em The LaTeX Companion}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, 1 edition, 1994.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Then you can add it into your cv like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-golden-upright}%
\quote{Some quote}

\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{adams}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\nocite{*}
\begin{thebibliography}{1} % <==========================================

\bibitem{adams}
Douglas Adams.
\newblock {\em The Restaurant at the End of the Universe}.
\newblock The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. Pan Macmillan, 1980.

\bibitem{Goossens}
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
\newblock {\em The LaTeX Companion}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, 1 edition, 1994.

\end{thebibliography} % <===============================================

\end{document}
```

It results in the following pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]