# Publications in moderncv with links

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, moderncv

Currently I am using `moderncv` the first time and everythings works great, but..
If I add my publications by:

```
% Publications
\renewcommand{\refname}{Veröffentlichungen}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Veröffentlichungen}
```

Then it doesn't include links.
But hyperlinks are important for me, because the publications are too huge to send it as an email attachment.

Here my header:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, color, final]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{footmisc}

% Theme
\moderncvtheme[red]{casual}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths

% Personal data
\firstname{Muster}
\familyname{Muster}
\title{Entwicklerin}
\photo[64pt]{Photo}

% Head
\begin{document}
\maketitle
...
```

Maybe i missed something..

Thank you, very much.

Comment: Do you get any error message? If yes please add it to your question. What do you mean with "Then it doesn't include links."? I see links using the moderncv template. Please complete your given code resulting in the missing link if I compile the code on my computer. (Then I do not have to guess what you are doing ...)

Comment: Please consider to upvote and mark my answer the accepted one if it was helpful for you or comment what is missing ...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, so let me guess a little bit:

1. you have urls in your bib entrys but they are not displayed in the resulting pdf.
2. you have not used command `\cite` to cite an article

**Solutions for 1.**

Let us say you have a bib entry like

```
@Article{bib_key_1,
  author    = {\textbf{Author 1} and Author 2 and Author 3 and Author 4 and Author 5},
  title     = {Research paper},
  journal   = {Journal of science},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {065008},
  month     = {may},
  doi       = {10.1088/1361-665x/aa6b66},
  publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66},
  keywords  = {press},
}
```

Your used style `plain` is very old and can not handle fields like `url =`  etc. To get an printed url in your bibliography add field `note =`  like

```
  note      = {\url{https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66}},
```

to the bib entry. Do this for all urls you need to be displayed and linked ...
Then you get for example the following result:

[image: Articles with printed links]

**Solution for 2.**

Use command `\cite{bib_key_1}` to cite an article with key `bib_key_1` from your bibliography like

```
 \cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{bib_key_1}} % <===================
```

to get an cited link to article number two in bibliography like this:

[image: cited article 2]

**Remarks to the following MWE:**

With the following complete bibliography file `Veröffentlichungen.bib`

```
@Article{bib_key_1,
  author    = {\textbf{Author 1} and Author 2 and Author 3 and Author 4 and Author 5},
  title     = {Research paper},
  journal   = {Journal of science},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {065008},
  month     = {may},
  doi       = {10.1088/1361-665x/aa6b66},
  publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66},
  keywords  = {press},
}
@Article{bib_key_2,
  author    = {\textbf{Author 1} and Author 2 and Author 3 and Author 4 and Author 5},
  title     = {Research paper},
  journal   = {Journal of science},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {065008},
  month     = {may},
  doi       = {10.1088/1361-665x/aa6b66},
  publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66},
  keywords  = {press},
  note      = {\url{https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66}},
}
@article{feynman,
  title     = {Very High-Energy Collisions of Hadrons},
  author    = {Richard P. Feynman},
  journal   = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume    = {23},
  issue     = {24},
  pages     = {1415--1417},
  year      = {1969},
  month     = {Dec},
  doi       = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  url       = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  note      = {\url{http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415}},
}
```

and the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,color,final,colorlinks=true]{moderncv} % <=============

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{red} % <=================================================

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{xurl} % <===================================================

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\recomputelengths

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe} % <====================================================
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-golden-upright}%
\quote{Some quote}

\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother

\setlength{\footskip}{69pt}


\begin{document}

\hypersetup{% <=========================================================
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=green, % black
% allcolors=color1, 
}% 
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{With cited article}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{bib_key_1}} % <===================
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Veröffentlichungen}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Veröffentlichungen}                        % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\end{document}
```

you get the following resulting pdf page:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please see important code changings marked in the MWE with `<=========`.

Please see that I defined own colors for urls and cited links with the following code:

```
\hypersetup{% <=========================================================
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=green, % black
% allcolors=color1, 
}%
```

Please see that changing the color for urls to green also changes the defined urls color in the footer. Use black to get not coloured links to your urls ...

Answer (score 0):

The `filecontent` part will create the file `references.bib` in your directory during the first compilation. Then run `bibtex`.
Should end with `Process exited normally`

After  that  compile twice. The references section will appear.

Be careful with filenames of the `.bib` file. Must be accepted by the OS. In mine, ö, é, or similar do not go.

[image: a]

Try this code.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
 \begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
    @book{yang2018optimization,
        title={Optimization Techniques and Applications with Examples},
        author={Yang, Xin-She},
        year={2018},
        publisher={John Wiley~\& Sons},
    }
    
    @book{kelley1999iterative,
        title={Iterative methods for optimization},
        author={Kelley, Carl T},
        year={1999},
        publisher={SIAM}
    }
    @book{cavazzuti2012optimization,
        title={Optimization methods: from theory to design scientific and technological aspects in mechanics},
        author={Cavazzuti, Marco},
        year={2012},
        publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
    }
    
    @book{grivet2012methodes,
        title={M{\'e}thodes num{\'e}riques appliqu{\'e}es pour le scientifique et l’ing{\'e}nieur (edition 2009): Edition 2013},
        author={Grivet, Jean-Philippe},
        year={2012},
        publisher={EDP sciences}
    }
    
    @article{lemarechal2012cauchy,
        title={Cauchy and the gradient method},
        author={Lemar{\'e}chal, Claude},
        journal={Doc Math Extra},
        volume={251},
        pages={254},
        year={2012}
    }
    @article{cauchy1847methode,
        title={M{\'e}thode g{\'e}n{\'e}rale pour la r{\'e}solution des systemes d’{\'e}quations simultan{\'e}es},
        author={Cauchy, Augustin},
        journal={Comp. Rend. Sci. Paris},
        volume={25},
        number={1847},
        pages={536--538},
        year={1847}
    }
    
            
        \end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, color, final]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{footmisc}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

% Theme
\moderncvtheme[red]{casual}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths

% Personal data
\firstname{Muster}
\familyname{Muster}
\title{Entwicklerin}
\photo[64pt]{Photo}

% Head
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \kant[1]
    
    \renewcommand{\refname}{Veröffentlichungen}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
%   \bibliography{Veröffentlichungen} do not use ö or similar in file names
    
    \bibliography{references} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
\end{document}
```